# php cli не работает

Tags: php

всем привет!
 столкнулся со странной проблемой, есть скрипт, начинается так

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

запускаю

```
./scriptname.php
```

в ответ:

> /usr/bin/env: вЂ�php\rвЂ™: No such file or directory

Comment: посмотри тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42881729/usr-bin-env-%C3%A2%E2%82%ACphp-r%C3%A2%E2%82%AC-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка из-за того что запускается **php\r**(присутствует символ возврата каретки), а не **php**
Поменяйте в скрипте формат строки на **LF** (Unix формат).
Также чтобы отображались нормально символы в терминале, поменяйте кодировку в ssh клиенте.